# Parse a url and return database rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to parse a url and connect to a database.

For instance when a user visits `url.php?id=1` they should get a list of questions and answers related to that topic.

When I run the MySQL query

```
SELECT * FROM QuestionDB WHERE TopicID = 1
```

In phpmyadmin I get the desired rows.

Here is my code. I returns a blank document!

```
$topic = $_GET['id'];

$dbhost = 'host';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'pass';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn ) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM QuestionDB WHERE TopicID = '$topic'';
mysql_select_db('mydb');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval ) {
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "Question :{$row['Question']}  <br> ".
        "Answer : {$row['Answer']} <br> ".
        "Author : {$row['Author']} <br> ".
        "--------------------------------<br>";
}

echo "Fetched data successfully\n";

mysql_close($conn);
```

I can't work out what I'm doing wrong. If I delete the `WHERE TopicID = '$topic'` portion of my query, this code does print out all the rows from my database.

Cheers in advance

Comment: What if you remove one of the ' after *$topic*?

Comment: Use `mysqli_` or PDO. The `mysql_` extension is deprecated and insecure.

Comment: this code has a large SQL injection security hole

Comment: As in someone could go to file.php?id=SOMESQL and do bad things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error. The string concatenation with the variable fails.

You have to change this line :

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM QuestionDB WHERE TopicID = "'.$topic.'"';
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM QuestionDB WHERE TopicID = '$topic'" ;
```

**Important note** : Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and may compromise the security of your database. You should use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/mysqli) APIs to secure your SQL queries, and using [`prepare`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) function.

Comment: Thanks. This no longer leaves me with a blank page. I get "Fetched data successfully". I assume in PHP i need to be careful with ' and ".
It still doesn't give me any data, though!

EDIT - Your edit ($sql = "SELECT * FROM QuestionDB WHERE TopicID = '$topic'") worked. Thank you. Why did that work, but $sql = 'SELECT * FROM QuestionDB WHERE TopicID = "$topic"';
didn't , I wonder?

Comment: @RichardTock Try to `var_dump($topic)` to see what's wrong.

Comment: Please add a warning that this may be vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Already added in comments but I will add. Thanks.

Comment: @Syscall Comments are very temporary, and can be removed for many reasons randomly. It's better to add it to the question so that future vistors who actually view the answer will see that there is a security hole. Thank you for editing.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I'm agree. Thanks.

Comment: @RichardTock I didn't see your update. I've updated my anwser between you get my first anwser (badly wrote), sorry. Both lines in anwser should works. Please check updated first line.